# "image/png;base64?" what does it do?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a question about this piece of code:

`redirectUrl`: `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="`

When I include this piece of code, all pictures on a website dont get loaded. But what does this encoder do?

Does it block pictures, hides them or just isn't loading them?

Comment: THIS bit of code does nothing. The sizeable chunk around it does.

Comment: `atob('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==')` is the binary data of your image.

Answer (score 2):

`data` describes the protocol. (like.. ftp, http, https etc.)
`:` separates the protocol from its parameters
since its data, the following chunk: `image/png` describes the type of the data.
At this position could come other information like content language etc.
`;base64` describes the encoding of the data
`,` separates the header from the data
`iVBORw0KG…` the actual data to be presented.

You can read more on it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Your provided png is a 1x1 pixel image that contains a transparent pixel.

Comment: but then why isnt it showing any pictures when i only include that code? what does it do with the pictures.

Comment: @kamitodono By itself, it doesn't. It's the code that's around this snippet that does something. Without context, I can guess what happens (from `redirectUrl` name), but it's impossible to answer in detail.

Answer (score 0):

data:image/png;base64 simply instructs the parser that it's a base 64 encoded png image. Make it a header if you will.